# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found). Cannot link js file

Tags: javascript, express, heroku

I'm trying to deploy a simple javascript/css/html app on heroku but I can't seem to link the js files properly. It works fine with no error without deploying.

This is my index.html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script type="text/javascript" 
        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body class="mt-0">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary ml-5 mt-5 position-fixed" style="right: 50px">Background mode</button>
    <-- more html code -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src='./js/sky-widget.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='./js/examples.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

server.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express();

const path = require('path');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/pub')));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('<h1>This should be the root route!</h1>')
})

// Error codes
app.get('/problem', (req, res) => {
    res.status(500).send('There was a problem on the server')
});


const port = process.env.PORT || 5000
app.listen(port, () => {
    log(`Listening on port ${port}...`)
})
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "weather-sky",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Weather widget library",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.4"
  }
}
```

And I get "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" on both sky-widget.js and examples.js

Any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Could you please add more information about the example.js / sky-widget.js.
Also could you try to change your static files for this:

- app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));